# NumberPicker doesn't return anything

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a dialog with 2 numberpickers (pickerMin & pickerSec). I want to use those numbers to make a text and to use them in a calculation.
However, it doesn't return anything at the moment. I've tried multiple ways of getting the numbers from the pickers and print those. I've even tried to set it to a TextView.

All I need is:

- The `NumberPicker` to give a number, which can be used outside the `Dialog` and in other parts of the project.
- To execute this when the user pressed the `klaar` button (the dialog disappears after this).

What exactly am I doing wrong and has to be done in order to get a result from the NumberPicker?

The broken part of the code:

```
public void show(){
    final Dialog timerDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    timerDialog.setTitle("Speeltijd helft");
    timerDialog.setContentView(R.layout.timerdialog);

    timerDialog.getWindow().setLayout(500, 600);

    klaar = (Button) timerDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnSetTimer);
    cancel = (Button) timerDialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelDialog);

    pickerMin = (NumberPicker) timerDialog.findViewById(R.id.pickerMin);
    pickerSec = (NumberPicker) timerDialog.findViewById(R.id.pickerSec);

    pickerMin.setMaxValue(45);
    pickerMin.setMinValue(0);
    pickerSec.setMaxValue(45);
    pickerSec.setMinValue(0);
    pickerMin.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    pickerSec.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);


    klaar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            pickerMin.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener(){
                @Override
               public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal){
                    minuten = picker.getValue();
                    out.println("pickerMin geeft: "+ minuten);
                }
            });

            pickerSec.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal){
                    seconden = picker.getValue();
                    out.println("pickerSec geeft: "+ seconden);
                }
            });

            Timerklok.setText(String.format("%02d", minuten)+":"+String.format("%02d",seconden)); //set the value to TextView
            timerDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            timerDialog.dismiss(); //dismiss dialog
        }
    });
    timerDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your problem should ideally be posted as a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That is, we should be able to copy and paste your code and have it compile and reproduce the problem you're having. We can't do that with this.

Comment: your calls to `setOnValueChangedListener` belong outside of the `onClickListener` - those don't get set until the button is pressed (but I think you mean to set them when the dialog is shown). One way to get those values outside of your dialog would be to assign them to a variable inside `onValueChange`, then add a `getter` method to your dialog class to return the value after the dialog returns. Another way would be to use the "Observer Pattern" - the click "listeners" and "valueChange" listeners in your current code are an example of this - you can define your own interface and do the same.